# @TransactionAttribute without @stateless or @stateful ? J2EE 6 - JBoss EAP 6

Tags: transactions, stateless, stateless-session-bean

if I specify @TransactionAttribute on a class, but I do NOT specify @stateless or @stateful, what is the behavior ? Will this be a session bean, or will the @TransactionAttribute just be ignored. ??

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class PhotosServiceImpl implements PhotosService
```

vs

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class PhotosServiceImpl implements PhotosService
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without @Stateless you can't inject it into other EJBs. If you instantiate it without doing injection, TransactionAttribute wouldn't kick in anyway.

So yes, TransactionAttribute on a non EJB class will have no effect.

Comment: what about @ Stateless with no @ TransactionAttribute. What would be the default behavior?